# I want My WCF service to use my web application config file which has multiple confirguration files for multiple clients as per branding

Tags: wcf

I have my web application hosted on Web server which has multiple configuration files (per client per theme) . So my connection strings are placed in theme.config for each theme.

We have already mapped directory with theme for eg(xxx.abc.com will pick theme xxx)

I have WCF service which has its own web config file and one connection string and now i want my WCF to use my hosted web application's theme.config for connection string.

I want to host my both (web application and WCF ) on cloud.

I read few articles on web about WebConfigurationFileMap but did not understand how i can implement with my WCF Service.

Need Help

Answer (score 0):

To acheive config file re-use separate out your web app connection strings into a separate config file and put a config source link in your WCF service config file pointing to connections strings config:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="(path to config)\connectionStrings.config" />
```

Comment: But my web app connection is based on branding and no single file is used for connection string. It depends on brand and how to apply brand to WCF application?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So at runtime how does your web app resolve the connection string?